# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel 5.3, nav.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get same view file nav.blade.php in different controllers but to get different content for admin and different for user but there is an error.

> error:View: /var/www/epharma/resources/views/nav.blade.php)

And the problem is this line

line 48:

```
@if(Auth::user()->type === 'User')
    <div> Html for user</div>
```

Comment: Post your code please!

Answer (score 2):

This will happen, when there is no logged in user. You can do something like this:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
  <p> Not logged in</p>

@elseif(Auth::user()->type === 'User')
  <p> Logged in</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
if(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->type === 'User')
```

it wont throw error if the first condition is false

Answer (score 0):

The user isn't authenticated So the `Auth::user()` is `Null`. And you are trying to get `null->id`. get id property from a non object (`null`).
You have to check firstly that the user is authenticated by `Auth::check()` or `Auth::user() != null` ..etc. and then try to get the user properties.

Answer (score 0):

Has been pretty much answered but you can do it like this as well

```
@if (Auth::guest())
  <p> Not logged in</p>

@elseif(Auth::user()->type == 'User')
  <p> Logged in</p>
@endif
```